# MongoDB Atlas SSL Connection reset by peer

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-odm, mongodb-atlas

I am using MongoDB Atlas cloud services with my Symfony 3 application and I am having lots of warnings in my PHP logs saying `MongoClient::__construct(): SSL: Connection reset by peer`. Even though I have warnings some times, I can connect successfully and read/write to the server.

I use Doctrine ODM which uses `MongoClient` for connecting to the server. I have configured the `replicaSet` according to MongoDB Atlas configuration.

When I look at MongoDB logs, I do not see any strange thing that appears to be linked to my issue.

Here is my connection string: `mongodb://<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>@datalake-shard-00-00-lnres.mongodb.net:27017,datalake-shard-00-01-lnres.mongodb.net:27017,datalake-shard-00-02-lnres.mongodb.net:27017/test?ssl=true&replicaSet=DataLake-shard-0&authSource=admin`

Here is my Doctrine ODM config

```
doctrine_mongodb:
    connections:
        default:
            server: "mongodb://<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>@datalake-shard-00-00-lnres.mongodb.net:27017,datalake-shard-00-01-lnres.mongodb.net:27017,datalake-shard-00-02-lnres.mongodb.net:27017/test?ssl=true&replicaSet=DataLake-shard-0&authSource=admin"
            options:
                authMechanism:  SCRAM-SHA-1
                authSource:     admin
                connect:        true
                ssl:            true
                password:       "<PASSWORD>"
                username:       "<USERNAME>"
                readPreference: secondaryPreferred
                replicaSet:     "DataLake-shard-0"
    default_database: "test"
    document_managers:
        default:
            auto_mapping: true
            retry_connect: 4
            retry_query:   4
```